# Jasper Report, iterate a list that has an object that contains another list

Tags: java, jasper-reports, javabeans

I must produce an excel file with Jasper Studio.

I pass to the jasper report a list called **listReport** that contains some attributes. One of these is an object that contains another list of another object.

Example:

The **listReport** is a list of:

```
public class ExampleObject{

private String a;
private String b;
private Object object;
...

public class Object{

private int c;
private List<AnotherObject> listAnotherObject;
...
```

In the excel there will be the informations about ExampleObject and also listAnotherObject.

It's is possible?

Comment: @AlexK, how can I do this?

Comment: Start checking how you use subreports and the JRBeanCollectionDataSource if you still run into problem past some jrxml code and I will help you out..